# Check the number of digits after the decimal part

Tags: javascript

I need to validate a number accordingly to its number of digits after the decimal part.

I am using with success the following code but, I would like to know:

- Is there another better way to achieve the same result? Maybe using some native Math functional.

Notes: I am aware of regular expression, but I am looking for a math approach.

```js
    var max = 2; // max number of digits after decimal places
        var value = 10.154;
        var s = value.toString().split('.')
        if (s[1].length > max) {
            alert('invalid');
        } else {
            alert('ok');
        }
```

Comment: Floating point numbers are just approximations. So, the value `10.154` might not be stored as `10.154`, itself. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Assuming the value is gonna be user provided, i think your solution is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the best way of doing it as there is no built in Javascript function that will achieve what you want.  This solution will work everywhere except in continental Europe where they use a comma(,) delimiter for decimals instead of a period(.)

You could also do this, but it wont work for negative numbers

```
var value = 10.154;
value = Math.abs(value);
var decimal = value - Math.floor(value)
var length = decimal.toString().length;
```

Comment: That still won't get you the number of digits, and I'm not sure that a number has a length property...

Comment: @DvS the edit i made should fix that problem.  Convert the number to a string and then grab the length

Comment: This won't work correctlybecause of floating point rounding issues

Answer (score 0):

You may use Python's `round()` function:

```py
>>> num = 10.542
>>> round(num, 2) == num
False
>>> num = 12.32
>>> round(num, 2) == num
True
```

Or

```py
>>> num = 12.32
>>> round(num, 2) >= num
True
>>> num = 12.3
>>> round(num, 2) >= num
True
>>> num = 12.324
>>> round(num, 2) >= num
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
var value = 10.154;
var length = value.toString().length - (value.toString().indexOf('.') + 1)
```

Answer (score -1):

In the computer, the number has a whole floating point decimal.  So 10.154 is in fact 10.15400000000 (to whatever level of accuracy the language goes).

So if you want to check if it has > max decimal values then you go:
you'll multiply the whole value with 10^x and then modulus 1 it.  If it's not 0 then you have more deceimal values than the max that you set.

So per your example 10.154 (3 decimal points) * 10^2 (your max) = 1015.4
1015.4 % 1 = 0.4 so "invalid"